# editing array items dynamically in react native

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, reactjs, react-native

This is my state and array :

```js
this.state = {
  arr: [{
    arrid: 0,
    arrEmail: '',
    arrName: '',
    arrPhone: ''
  }],
  id: 0,
  email: "",
  isChecked: true,
  name: "",
  phone: "",
  isOpen: false,
  editedEmail: '',
  editedName: '',
  editedPhone: ''
};
```

This is the place where they are getting edited :

```js
updateEmail = value => {
  this.setState({ editedEmail: value });
};
updateName = value => {
  this.setState({ editedName: value });
};
updatePhone = value => {
  this.setState({ editedPhone: value });
};
```

This the function of editing an element dynamically:

```js
editData = (row) => {
  this.refs.modal2.close();
  var arr3 = this.state.arr;
  var arrid = this.state.id;
  var index = arr3.indexOf(row);
  var editedName = this.state.editedName;
  var editedEmail = this.state.editedEmail;
  var editedPhone = this.state.editedPhone;

  this.setState({
    arrid: arrid,
    arrEmail: editedEmail,
    arrName: editedName,
    arrPhone: editedPhone
  });
}
```

But it is not getting edited. Firstly, they are not getting stored in.

```
arr3
```

Comment: Are you using modal to edit the fields? If yes then the state mentioned is the the state of modal or component?

Comment: @nehasoni the state mentioned (isOpen) is for the modal and it is not being used u can ignore that

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your editData function:

```
this.setState({arr:[...arr3.map(item=>item.arrid===arrid?{...item,arrEmail:editedEmail, arrName:editedName, arrPhone:editedPhone }:item)]});
```

Comment: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/vamsi/Desktop/moodcafe/App.js: Unexpected token (86:19)

  84 | editData=(row)=>{
  85 | this.refs.modal2.close();
> 86 | this.setState(arr:[...arr3.map(item=>item.arrid===arrid?{...item,arrEmail:editedEmail, arrName:editedName, arrPhone:editedPhone }:item)]);
     |                    ^
  87 | 
  88 | }

Comment: sorry. I edited my answer. setState arqument should be an object